# How can i use special characters in IE 6

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6

How can i use special characters in IE 6 ? 
for exmple : for ș (LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH COMMA BELOW)

I use `&#537;` but it did not work

Thank you in advance

Comment: hmm, I don't think IE6 can display that character at all. I was going to suggest using UTF-8 encoding so you didn't need the entity, but that doesn't work either. So the only things I can suggest are drop the character and use a plain "s" instead, or drop IE6 support. (I suggest the latter)

Comment: For ref: [a jsFiddle that demonstrates it not working](http://jsfiddle.net/v5eQp/1/embedded/result/).

Answer (score 1):

Fonts shipped with old versions of Windows where you can use IE 6 apparently do not cntain the character LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH COMMA BELOW. Since it would be unrealistic to expect users to install new fonts just to see some special characters, the best shot is to use U+015F LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH CEDILLA instead, either the character “ş” as such or as the character reference `&#15f; or`ş`.

From the Unicode perspective, s with comma below and s with cedilla are glyph variants, but they have been defined as separate characters as requested by the Romanian standards institute, to allow the distinction to be made at the character level. However, even in Romania, this distinction is not made consistently at all, and s with cedilla has a much better font coverage.